# Why does my texture look odd? UV scemes too obvious for no reason, light behaves oddly, geometry unsmoothed in render

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, texture-painting, texture-baking

It was modelled Nomad and Zbrush, retopo in 3D Coat, UV mapped in Rizom, textures were painted in Zbrush. The rendering engin used is Evee and the shader is the standard Principled BSDF.

I do not understand why the texturing looks like a patchwork quilt, the light seems to behave differently on each UV island giving the character a stuffed toy appearance  despite the model having its topology smoothed, it still has this low poly appearance up close.

**Maps used are Colour, Normal and bump map**

Someone has made these suggestions to me,

- **UV seams**, we cant see anything to suggest a problem on my maps.

-**shader my not be tiling correctly** How do I check this?

- **ambient colour being different between UV shells** the model has been painted in Zbrush, I am not sure how this issue may occur.
- **mesh normals not facing camera** I have not played with the mesh in any way that should flip normals, I used to have this issue when modelling the old fashioned way before I used Nomad or Zbrush.
- **render time subdivisions**,can't find this option in Evee to do anything with it if thats the case.
- is the issue how the differnt maps are interacting with the shader?

Have any of you had anything similar, how did you fix it? I want to point out that this is the first time I have used Blender seriously, I need this to look good.Should I be using Evee? Is Cycles better? Am I using th wrong shader?

Would baking the texture solve the issue? using displacement and bake a high resolution sculpt on a medium poly mesh, I have no idea how you define a low or medium poly mesh. I do not really want to have to retopologise the mesh again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIhNh.jpg)[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello make sure that the normal map is set to Non-Color instead of sRGB, if it doesn't fix your problem please pack your image and share your file